# How to popupWindow from different activities

Tags: java, android, popup

I started Android programming like 3 days ago and I'm getting trouble with the PopupWindows. My idea is to show some detail about my app in the context menu (the default button is called Settings) so when the button is cliced, a Popupwindow must appear.

I've here my class, the one I should call from every other class relatid with any activity in order to show the popup.

```
public class MostrarDetallesApp extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

PopupWindow popupWindow;

public void detallesApp(MenuItem item) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.detallesaplicacion, null);
    View background = this.getCurrentFocus();
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    Button cerrarDetallesApp = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.cerrarDetallesAppButton);
    cerrarDetallesApp.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(background,Gravity.CENTER,Gravity.CENTER,Gravity.CENTER);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Toast);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.update();


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    popupWindow.dismiss();
}
```

}
The dismiss is related with a button that the popupwindow has in order to close it. Now my question is, how can I call that popup from every class so I can avoid copying the code in every single of them?

I should make that one static but if i do that, method like this.getCurrentFocus(); get unusable.

I'm not 100% of whatevery syntax word does because I invested like 3-4 hours looking for how to popup the window from that menu so, for example, I could tell you that MenuItem item must be called there because somehow it recognizes when the user clicks the button.

Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a object of this class using context parameter and then call shoWwindow():

In Activity call:

```
MostrarDetallesApp obj=new MostrarDetallesApp(this);
obj.showWindow();


public class MostrarDetallesApp implements View.OnClickListener {
PopupWindow popupWindow;
private Context context;

MostrarDetallesApp(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void showWindow() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.detallesaplicacion,
            null);
    View background = this.getCurrentFocus();
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button cerrarDetallesApp = (Button) popupView
            .findViewById(R.id.cerrarDetallesAppButton);
    cerrarDetallesApp.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(background, Gravity.CENTER, Gravity.CENTER,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Toast);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.update();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    popupWindow.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your help, really :)
Im just getting problems with the "this.getCurrentFocus();

Comment: My problem comes when calling popupWindow.shotAtLocation(background...
The thing is that this method needs a view to show the popup over, but i just simply dont know how to call it from another class.

Comment: Now i'm getting NullPointerExpcetion at
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: where you are using getBaseContext(). dont use getBaseContext instead of that use context you have a context as feild.

Comment: Thank you so much, really. I dolove you ♥